# R to Python translation problem in element wise logical condition

Tags: python, r, logical-operators

I have the following code in R :

```
N = 100 # number of data points
unifvec = runif(N)
d1 = rpois(sum(unifvec < 0.5),la1);d1
```

```
 [1] 3 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 3 0
[32] 2 2 1 4 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 3 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 1 3
```

Trying to translate it in Python I am doing :

```
la1 = 1
N = 100 # number of data points
unifvec = np.random.uniform(0,1,N)
d1 = np.random.poisson(la1,sum(la1,unifvec < 0.5))
```

but I receive an error :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How I can reproduce the same result in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum` function receives arguments in the wrong order.

After changing `sum(la1,unifvec < 0.5)` to `sum(unifvec < 0.5, la1)` it works fine.

```py
import numpy as np

la1 = 1
N = 100  # number of data points
unifvec = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)
d1 = np.random.poisson(la1, sum(unifvec < 0.5, la1))
```

Comment: and if I do `d2 = np.random.poisson(la2, sum(unifvec > 0.5 and unifvec < 0.7))` the same as you told me I receive an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() `

Comment: This error is caused by `unifvec > 0.5 and unifvec < 0.7`.

Comment: how can I fix this ?

Comment: probably this `d2 = np.random.poisson(la2,sum( (unifvec > 0.5) & (unifvec <0.7)  ) );d2`